# Skip or ignore the first occurence of a word in a substring

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTR(eventlogs.message,LOCATE('Account Name:',eventlogs.message)+13,
LOCATE('Account Domain:',eventlogs.message)-
(LOCATE('Account Name:',eventlogs.message)+13)) 
AS `SourceAccount` FROM eventlogs
```

I need to skip or ignore the first occurrence of `Account Name:` and return this same info for the second occurrence of `Account Name:`

Comment: Please help....

Comment: pls show us sample data and exected result. Thx